# Stability of roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, stability-theory

I'm given the time-dependent polynomial $$p(x_t,x^*_{t-1},t)=x_t^3+ax_t^2+b(t)x_t+c(x^*_{t-1},t),$$
where $a$ is constant, $b(t)$ is a time-dependent parameter and $c(x^*_{t-1},t)$ also depends on the previous root $x^*_{t-1}$.
I want to study the stability of its time-dependent roots $x_t^*$, i.e.the solution to $p(x^*_t,x^*_{t-1},t)=0$ as a sequence in time. From numerical simulations I know that the sequence stabilizes if perturbed and converges back to the same value. But I want to prove that this is the case and ideally for what size of perturbations it becomes unstable. Naively, I tried plugging in $x_t\to x_t^*+\varepsilon$ and look at when the first order coefficient of $\varepsilon$ is negative, as this usually does imply linear stability (for ODEs), however I don't know if this is correct. I'm not sure what approach to use, as this isn't a map, i.e. $x_{t+1}=f(x_t)$, or an ODE.

Comment: Not very clear. You write $x_t$ which suggests $x$ depends on $t$: how? (doesn't seem to make sense) You write that "it" stabilizes? What stabilizes, with the variation of what? What is the perturbation? My guess would be the coefficients of $p$ depend on $t$, and you look at the evolution of the roots as $t$ grows, and the influence of a perturbation of the polynomial on the roots (but I still have no clue about the kind of perturbation).

Comment: I tried to improve the question, maybe it's clearer now

Comment: Ok. I still don't see why you write $x_t$. Of course the roots $x_t^*$ depends on $t$, but $x_t$ does not, it's the indeterminate of the polynomial $p$ (whose *coefficients* depend on $t$). Since $t-1$ is the *previous*, I assume $t$ is an integer?

Comment: I added the index to make it similar to iterative sequences, and yes, $t$ is an integer. You don't the index, though